# How to display function result from a class to the view in angular/typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

let's say I have the following model :

```
module Model {  
interface IProduct{
        id: number;
        name: string;
        price: number;

        discount(): number;
}

export class Product implements IProduct {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;

    constructor(id: number, name: string, price: number) {

    }

    discount(): number{
            return this.price - 10*this.price/100;
    }
}
}
```

I was wondering if I can use `vm.product.discount` in a view, and it would calculate the discount based on the actual product's price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if I can use vm.product.discount in a view, and it would calculate the discount based on the actual product's price?

Yup. For example in your HTML just call the function:

```
<div>{{vm.product.discount()}}</div>
```

Comment: been trying that, but it didnt.might be linked to something else in my app. I am not sure.